# Ranking categories against all other customers

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau workbook that has a series of packaging types (Clamshell, Corrugate, Misc, etc). Each customer has total sales by some if not all of those categories, based on what was sold to them in the previous year.

What I'm trying to do is build a rank that shows how that customer did in the given category compared to all other customers. All I'm able to do right now is how each of the categories rank against each other, when I select a given customer vs ranking those sales by category across all customers.

Current Example (categories ranked against each other for the given customer)

Customer A

Category A: 1

Category B: 2

Category C: 3

Category D: 4

How it should read, if compared against all customers (each category is ranked for that given category vs all other customers not selected)

Customer A:

Category A: 124

Category B: 15

Category C: 35

Category D: 45

Does anyone know how to build this kind of rank?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tableau uses an [order of operations](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/order_of_operations.htm) to filter visuals. The result you see is happening due to when dimension filters are executed in this order of ops.  You can 'trick' Tableau into filtering differently.  Try this; create a new calculated field on your category dimension: lookup(min(category),0).  Now, use this calc as your filter. This causes Tableau to evaluate the dimension as a measure...effectively keeping the underlying data intact.

Comment: Hi rdugge, the problem is I have a customer name context filter on the dashboard filtering data across multiple views for a given customer. If I do this calculation, I would have to filter the customer on the dashboard in two different places. Is it possible to filter both the ranked fields and the other views using a single set of customers?